# Azure Wordpress Site Returns 500 Errors After Plugin Update

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, azure, caching

I have a Wordpress site which is hosted on Microsoft Azure, and the site is located at http://bitcoinpricelive.com

I recently updated a plugin called W3 Total Cache. After doing this the site was returning errors and going to wp-admin told me there was a problem with that plugin and i needed to delete: advanced-cache.php and object-cache.php

I deleted those two files but then the wp-admin page showed no information at all. I documented this aspect a bit more on Wordpress forums: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/w3-total-cache-error-after-updating-plugin/

Additionally, I tried googling for many fixes to this problem from modifying the .htaccess file to deleting W3 Total Cache components.

On the Azure side of things I get errors from source: W3SVC-WP, event id: 2289, and from source: W3SVC-WP, event id: 2284. I have been looking at documentation on the Microsoft site as well here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734951(v=ws.10).aspx

I can still login to the server via FileVilla and make changes if needed.

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to uninstall the extension via Azure's web portal, restart the app. Delete the extensions dir using SCM (https://my_app_subdomain.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole). Restart the app again. And maybe redeploy your app. It's possible the plugin messed with .htaaccess or something.

From Willian: Try delete the w3-cache directory in wp-content.

Comment: That Kudu portal is really helpful. Where do I find that extensions dir you mentioned?

I download a dump file for website and under LogFiles\DetailedErrors there are some html pages which show this error is occurring:

Module: FastCgiModule
Notification: ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler: PHP55_via_FastCGI
Error Code: 0x00000000
Requested URL: http://bitcoinpricelive:80/index.php
Physical Path: D:\home\site\wwwroot\index.php
Logon Method: Anonymous
Logon User: Anonymous

Comment: Extensions are placed in the D:\home\SiteExtensions dir. I would do this after uninstalling all extensions via the tool first at mysubdomain.scm.azurewebsites.net/SiteExtensions/#installed

Comment: Under ..SiteExtensions/#installed it does not show any installed and just has a message "Site extensions can be installed from the Gallery." I installed/updated the W3 Total Cache plugin through the wordpress console. Any other ideas for what to check?

Comment: Oh I got it working now! I needed to delete the w3-cache directory in wp-content. If you want to add that to your answer I can click that you solved it... thanks for the help.